# Question Tag Scores

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-score

I think it would be nice to have a similar tag score display for questions, separate from your answer tag score.

Stack users love statistics, and this could open up new badge possibilities like, perhaps: "Inquirer of [tag name]"

Edit: I know you can see your scores of a specific tag via the title attribute, but this would display it more openly. I don't know why it's "hidden" like it is already.

Comment: I'm not sure I see any benefit. Certainly you know what tags you've asked questions in, and others have no need to know that information. I really don't care if someone has asked a question related to any of the tags I monitor. It might make a difference whether they'd ever *answered* a question in that tag on occasion. (Not downvoting the idea, but not convinced of its usefulness.)

Comment: Go and write your own! http://data.stackexchange.com/