# Regression in new "Ask" page: tag usage guidance (tips) has been de-emphasized and is not obvious

Tags: feature-request, ask-question-form, tag-tips

We got tag tips, they are little guidance flavor that is supposed to try to nudge you into asking better questions when you use some tags on the site. Well, I doubt askers are reading it because it's muted:

[image]

Given that it's in the right side of the screen where users are used to have stuff they can ignore, this guidance is very likely lost on many askers. Previously, it was a message box that was contextual to the tag box, now it's just something that seemly replace what was there (that I also was blind to). Can the tag tips be more in-your-face, please?

Comment: Buttons: [Yes, I have followed this advice]; [No, I need to edit my question]

Answer (score 2):

It looks that the [tag-tips](/questions/tagged/tag-tips) went from "screaming on the ear" to "softly whispering on a noisy room"

For first time posters, the [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground) project might help to make the posters to take seriously the guidance provided on the *tag-tips*.

For other posters I think that the user question [tag-score](/questions/tagged/tag-score) to set the "sound level" of the "tag-tips", similar to a clock alarm that start softly and slowly it increase the sound and vibration level until it's turned off, but instead of starting with a very low level, start with medium level and change the level based on the question score: increasing the score reduce the level, decreasing the score increase the level.

Related

- [Question Tag Scores](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274608/1595451)
- [What does 'score' really represent?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400092/1595451)