# Will tag-tips be used in the next Ask Question page?

Tags: support, tag-tips, ask-question-wizard

Will [tag-tips](/questions/tagged/tag-tips) or tag-warnings be available in the next iteration of the Ask Question page? They aren't mentioned in [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground) questions.

For people who are unfamiliar with tag-tips or tag-warnings, I quote from *[The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691)* (from March, 2020):

> - The warning text shown in the "Review your question" sidebar, regex-based (seen with the default text in screenshot 4, and with custom text on screenshot 5).
> - Tag-related error messages and warnings, regex-based (seen with custom error text in screenshot 4, with the default text on screenshot 5, and with a tag warning [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VrTS.png)).
> - The warning and error messages described in the two bullet points above have a limit of 1000 characters.

This is the image linked in the above quote

[image]

Related

- [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/1595451)
- [What determines what tags will get a popup with usage guidance?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354934/1595451)
- [Regression in new "Ask" page: tag usage guidance (tips) has been de-emphasized and is not obvious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419757/1595451)

Comment: To be honest, this feels pretty useless – at least if it works the way shown in the screenshot. With tags being last in the wizard, the tips can only be shown *after* the content has already been written. That some issues of the content are automatically highlighted and named also softly implies that un-highlighted things aren't issues, i.e. that the content is fine without adhering to the tips.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for your reply. I think that it supports what Braiam said on [Regression in new "Ask" page: tag usage guidance (tips) has been de-emphasized and is not obvious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419757/1595451).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it will be available and should be still available. It's a good thing to have that box there, **especially** for new users. Users who aren't familiar with the site will lead to some questions sometimes.  The tag-tips box helps reduce that.

However of course 1 possible problem of this box is it being too **hidden**. It is far on the right, despite being big, but I'm not sure if that can be resolved.

Comment: Re *"being too hidden"*: Yes, it may be ignored or overlooked. A (real) [usability](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) study could reveal it (it doesn't have to be very involved).